# Как сделать графическое отображение процесса на Python

Tags: python

Есть к примеру неотсортированный массив [4,5,3,2,1],он стал отсортированным [1,2,3,4,5].Как на графике показать, как меняется массив [4,5,3,2,1] на [1,2,3,4,5]

Comment: «на графике»? хм. а как вы себе представляете таковой вот график?

Comment: Не нужно дублировать один и тот же вопрос несколько раз.